# BizTalk Sftp Receive Location cant get Attributes ( Event Log )

Tags: biztalk, winscp, winscp-net, biztalk-2020

We are using BizTalk Server 2020 with a Receive Location ( Sftp Adapter - Winscp ), which downloads files from a Sftp Server.
The Url we poll the files from is: sftp://://* ( so we poll all the files located in root directory ).

Every time we poll a file we receive following Event Log Warning:

```
The adapter "SFTP" raised an error message. Details "Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Sftp.SftpAdapterException: Failed to delete file '/File' from the SFTP server. ---> WinSCP.SessionRemoteException: Can't get attributes of file '/File'.
No such file or directory.
Error code: 2
Error message from server: The message [/File] is not extractable!
   at WinSCP.SessionLogReader.Read(LogReadFlags flags)
   at WinSCP.ElementLogReader.Read(LogReadFlags flags)
   at WinSCP.SessionElementLogReader.Read(LogReadFlags flags)
   at WinSCP.ElementLogReader.Read(LogReadFlags flags)
   at WinSCP.ElementLogReader.ReadToEnd(LogReadFlags flags)
   at WinSCP.Session.DoGetFileInfo(String path)
   at WinSCP.Session.GetFileInfo(String path)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Sftp.SftpFileReceiver.DownloadComplete(String fileName, Boolean deleteFile)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

It seems like the Sftp Server does not support operations including attributes.

I would like to avoid these kind of warnings by ignoring them ( within Receive Location or WinScp ) although the files are received successfully.
Is there a dedicated suppress setting for it?
Are there any other ways to avoid this kind of warning except fixing it on Sftp Server?

In WinScp there is only a setting for upload options but not for download:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *"operations including attributes"*? What does the WinSCP *GUI* screenshot have to do with your question? – Anyway, after the download, the BizTalk Server seems to query information about the just downloaded file again (to verify the download?). Your server does not seem to like that for some reason. Do you know why?

Comment: with "operations including attributes" i meant that uploading or downloading a file.
WinScp is used for BizTalk Sftp Adapter and also configuration of it. Thats why i showed that WinScp only has Upload Ignoration setting.

I dont know why this happens exactly...

Comment: Are you sure the adapter uses WinSCP GUI configuration? The adapter uses WinSCP .NET assembly which does not by default use WinSCP GUI configuration (It might be (mis)configured to do so, though). – In any case, no WinSCP GUI configuration can affect this, as the the callstack makes it pretty clear that it's adapter's own decision that it queries the file attributes, not WinSCP's decision (btw, do post callstacks as text, not as an image).

Comment: Well - i think that our Server uses winscp configuration because it uses winscp to connect to sftp servers, but im not 100% sure about it.

Comment: Looks more like a permissions issue on the SFTP server that is not letting you delete the files.  Also can you please post the error message as text, rather than an image?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf From the wording of the error message (*"The message ... is not extractable"*), it looks like it's not a normal SFTP server (running over a file system), but rather an SFTP interface to some other kind of proprietary system. So it's probably not permissions as such, but rather that the system does not support deleting or that it might delete the "message" automatically after it is downloaded.

Comment: i've just replaced the image with the stacktrace.
Just for your information,our receive location receives files properly and i assume that also our receive location is responsible for file deletion - but unfortunately we receive these kind of Event Log Warnings.
@Dijkgraaf did you ever ran into this kind of behavior?
So regarding my question it looks like there is no way avoiding these Event Log Warnings, right?

Comment: It looks like it is only faling on the delete part. So just set the receive location not to delete the files (it will then use timestamp comparison to see if it needs to pick it up).

Comment: I have set Retain after Download and Timestamp Comparison within Sftp Receive Location to True - although the File gets deleted and still throws the warning into our Event Log.
Does this mean that there is an automatic file deletion configured on sftp server side and because this happens during our session, we receive this warning within our event log?

Comment: We cannot answer that. Only the server owner can. But indeed, it's quite likely. This is no longer a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

We updated the SFTP adapter in BizTalk 2020 CU5 to also support more variants of SFTP "MFT" type of servers where they rename or move files after they have been received. More errors related to this should now be ignored.

Please update to CU5 and check if you still see these kind of errors. Else there might be more information in the receive location log file if you enable this to understand more what is happening.